# Get nearest date value group by each item

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Table t1 has the following structure

```
|  id  |      from             |  item   |    p    |
    1    2014-03-26 08:00:00       500        9
    2    2014-03-28 14:30:00       500        7
    3    2014-03-29 14:30:00       200        48
    4    2014-04-01 19:00:00       200        51
    5    2014-03-30 23:30:00       500        6
```

How can I select for each item the only the record with date nearest date to now IN THE PAST?

```
SELECT t1.`from`, t1.item, t1.item 
  FROM t1
WHERE t1.`from` <= NOW()
  ORDER BY `from` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This limits the results to 1 item

And this

```
SELECT t1.`from`, t1.item, t1.item 
  FROM t1
WHERE t1.`from` <= NOW()
  GROUP BY item
```

returns the oldest record foreach element not the nearst to now.

What should I use?

**EDIT**

Expected result now (2014-03-31 15:30:00)

```
|  id  |      from             |  item   |    p    |
    3    2014-03-29 14:30:00       200        48
    5    2014-03-30 23:30:00       500        6
```

Result I get:

```
|  id  |      from             |  item   |    p    |
    1    2014-03-26 08:00:00       500        9
    3    2014-03-29 14:30:00       200        48
```

Server time is perfect!

**EDIT2**

```
SELECT t1.`from`, t1.p, prod_desc.name AS prod
  FROM PROD_DESC
  JOIN 
    (SELECT MAX(t1.`from`) `from`, t1.id
       FROM t1
     GROUP BY prod) t2 USING(`from`, id)
  LEFT JOIN t1
    ON t1.item = PROD_DESC.id_prod
WHERE t1.`from` <= NOW()
```

Comment: What should the desired result set look like... and is there an sqlfiddle?

Comment: I edited my answer with the expected result. `sqlfiddle.com` is down, I get a runtime error

Comment: It happens. Try again in a few minutes. Or just paste the DDLs here.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with paste the DDLs here? :/

Comment: That's where google comes in! ;-)

Comment: @Perocat - the nearest result to "2014-03-31 15:30:00" is "2014-04-01 19:00:00" and not "2014-03-29 14:30:00"!

Comment: sorry, only past results!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DDLs...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,`from`             DATETIME NOT NULL
,item   INT NOT NULL
,p    INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'2014-03-26 08:00:00',500,9),
(2,'2014-03-28 14:30:00',500,7),
(3,'2014-03-29 14:30:00',200,48),
(4,'2014-04-01 19:00:00',200,51),
(5,'2014-03-30 23:30:00',500,6);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+---------------------+------+----+
| id | from                | item | p  |
+----+---------------------+------+----+
|  1 | 2014-03-26 08:00:00 |  500 |  9 |
|  2 | 2014-03-28 14:30:00 |  500 |  7 |
|  3 | 2014-03-29 14:30:00 |  200 | 48 |
|  4 | 2014-04-01 19:00:00 |  200 | 51 |
|  5 | 2014-03-30 23:30:00 |  500 |  6 |
+----+---------------------+------+----+
```

Solution:

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT item
            , MAX(`from`) max_from 
         FROM my_table 
        WHERE `from` <= NOW() 
        GROUP 
           BY item
     ) y 
    ON y.item = x.item 
   AND y.max_from = x.`from`;
+----+---------------------+------+----+
| id | from                | item | p  |
+----+---------------------+------+----+
|  3 | 2014-03-29 14:30:00 |  200 | 48 |
|  5 | 2014-03-30 23:30:00 |  500 |  6 |
+----+---------------------+------+----+
```

Comment: WOOOOOOOOW! That's perfect!!! THANK YOU!!! One more question: why `FROM my_table x` instead of `FROM my_table AS x`? Same thing? Also for `BY item) (AS) y`?

Comment: a little less typing - and don't use reserved words as column/table identifiers (yuk)

Comment: Yes, sorry! I simple translated this from italian `da` to english `from`. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using self join on the maximum values

```
SELECT t.*
FROM t1 t 
JOIN 
(SELECT MAX(t1.`from`) `from`,item ,t1.id
FROM t1 t1
WHERE `from` <= NOW()
GROUP BY item 
) t2 USING(`from`,item)
```

@Strawberry he was right the regarding the placement of where clause and also the join should be on `USING(`from`,item)` compound condition

Comment: I think you're WHERE clause is (technically) in the wrong place

Comment: I posted the complete query with this integrated, but I get a couple of errors... (see question)

Comment: @Perocat where you have posted ? *I get a couple of errors* can you mention them

Comment: @Perocat you asked for the nearest date less than = now so today is `2014-03-31` and may be your server time is greater than `15:30:00` therefore you are getting `2014-03-31 15:30:00` which is correct expected result

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid As I've tried to explain, your logic is flawed. See my solution nearby.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

**...and after the last question change this is true again:**

```
SELECT t1.`from`, t1.item, t1.item 
FROM t1
WHERE t1.`from` <= NOW()
GROUP BY item
ORDER BY t1.`from` DESC
```

**Edit after condition changed**

```
SELECT t1.`from`, t1.item, t1.item 
FROM t1
GROUP BY item
ORDER BY ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND,t1.`from`,NOW()))
```

**And edit again for the final edit**

This time I have the db and checked the results - they match with what you've expect!

```
SELECT t2.`from`, t2.item, t2.item
FROM ( SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE t1.`from` <= NOW() ORDER BY t1.`from` DESC ) AS t2
GROUP BY t2.item
```

Comment: Doesn't return the nearest date, but the oldest

Comment: @Perocat - check it now

Comment: @Perocat - I've double checked the results this time against a real db. They match your expectations in your last update.

Answer (score -2):

Convert the dates to timestamps and then sort them by difference from current time timestamp in the end limit the result to 1 so You get only the nearest one.